# Redmine Apache Passenger error: Unexpected error in mod_passenger

Tags: apache, redmine

Error message given by Apache:

```
[ pid=26810 thr=140719191291712 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:862 time=2014-01-27 10:57:06.221 ]:
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to Unix socket
'/tmp/passenger.1.0.25998/generation-0/socket': Permission denied (13)
Backtrace: [Truncated...]
```

As a temporary fix, changing owner `apache:apache` of `/tmp/passengerXXX` solves the issue.

But when restart apache, this directory is owned by root and error.

Help me @@

Comment: Find the service creates this folder `/tmp/passengerXXX`, and in the config there should be a way to change permission (or run in as a different user). `grep -rn passenger /etc/` might help.